# using setupFiles to run asynchronous code

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, asynchronous, jestjs

How can I run the files inside setupFiles array to finish first before the tests are downloaded and executed and how can I iterate the values from the setupFiles code in testing.

The data from setupFiles code is assigned to the global object and there are two things occurring.
1. The test suite runs instantly with the setupFiles code. 
2. The values are not accessible in the test code because they are undefined, but if I nest them inside another describe block they become accessible but still I am not able to loop through them to run a test against.

I have tried setting up the values through the set up and tear down of beforeAll and added timers.

```
index.js

(async () => {
 const events = [
    'dialog',
    'request',
    'response'
]
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false })
const page = await browser.newPage()
events.forEach(event =>{
  page.on(event, async(eventType) =>{
      if(event === 'dialog') {
          return eventType.accept()
      }
      else if(event === 'response') {
          if(eventType.url().includes('trending')) {
              let data = await eventType.json().then(res => res).catch(e => console.error(e.message))
              global.data = data
          }
      }
      else {
        console.log('ಠ_ಠ ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Nothing To See here ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ಠ_ಠ')
    }
  })
})
await page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 1307 })
await page.goto('https://www.giphy.com/')
await browser.close()

})()

workflow.test.js

describe('giphy', () =>{
beforeAll(async() =>{
    console.log(global.data)
})
global.data.forEach(element =>{
    it('wants to show up', async() =>{
        await expect(element).toHaveProperty('title')
    })
 })
})

package.json

"jest": {
"verbose": true,
"setupFiles": ["<rootDir>/index.js"]
},
```

I expect the setupFiles to run asynchronously and the values to be available to be iterated upon.

Comment: Any reason you don't just call the `asnyc` function from `index.js` inside a `beforeAll` in `workflow.test.js`?  Then you wouldn't need to use `global` because the data would be local to your test, and passing an `async` function to `beforeAll` means `Jest` will wait for it to complete before running the tests.

Comment: That is the first thing I tried, the data is not available when the async call is completed. @brian-lives-outdoors

Answer (score 0):

Jest does not support this type of workflow, I accomplished this by launching the code prior to Jest and preparing the data I needed in a file, using fs.writeStream().